# Adjusting Text Vertical Space between lines in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, tikz-styles

I have this flowchart and the preamble is set to add a vertical space  between lines and when I compiled this flowchart it follwed the preamble i guess. how can I adjust the vertical spaces of lines in my flow chart without affecting the other parts of the document

[image]

```
\tikzstyle{inpro}=[circle, thick, draw=yellow!50, fill=yellow!20, minimum size=3mm]
\tikzstyle{mater} = [rectangle, thick, draw=green!50, fill=green!20, minimum width=2.25cm, minimum height=.5cm, text centered]
\tikzstyle{react} = [rectangle, thick, draw=cyan!50, fill=cyan!20, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm, text centered, text width=2cm]


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.25cm]
\node(mater)[mater]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(inpro1)[inpro, below of=mater]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(inpro2)[inpro, right of=inpro1]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(react1)[react, right of=inpro2]{\tiny Bubble Bubble};
\node(dummy)[right of=react1]{};
\node(dummy3)[right of=dummy]{};
\node(inpro3)[inpro, above of=dummy3]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(mater2)[mater, right of=inpro3]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(dummy4)[below of=dummy3]{};
\node(react2)[react, right of=dummy3]{\tiny Bubble Bubble Bubble};
\node(inpro4)[inpro, right of=dummy4]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(mater3)[mater, below of=dummy4]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(dummy5)[below of=mater3]{};
\node(inpro5)[inpro, left of=dummy5]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(mater4)[mater, below of=dummy5]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(react3)[react, draw=magenta!50, fill=magenta!20, left of=inpro5]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(inpro6)[inpro, left of=react3]{\tiny Bubble};
\node(mater5)[mater, left of=inpro6]{\tiny Bubble Bubble};


\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](mater)--(inpro1);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](inpro1)--(inpro2);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](inpro2)--(react1);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50, dashed](react1)|-(inpro3);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](mater2)--(inpro3);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](inpro3)|-(react2);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](react2)--(inpro4);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](inpro4)|-(mater3);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](mater3)-|(inpro5);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](mater4)-|(inpro5);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](inpro5)--(react3);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](react3)--(inpro6);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](inpro6)--(mater5);
\draw [->, ultra thick, draw=orange!50, dashed](react1)--(dummy)|-node[anchor=southwest]{}(inpro4);
\draw [->, dashed, ultra thick, draw=orange!50](react1)--(react3);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can always use `\\[<amount of vertical space>]` where you want more vertical space.

Comment: Not related but you can avoid writing `\tiny ...` in every node with `node font=\tiny` option.

Comment: And how exactly are you increasing the value for baselineskip (the vertical separation between lines)? Are you, for example, using the `setspace` package or are you redefining some command?

Comment: @Ignasi It solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @dcmst Thanks for the idea I'll use this next time.

Comment: You can add ```\linespread{1.0}``` in the figure code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.